# My dark room mob spawner isn't working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've build a mobspawner but they are not spawning. 
The light level is 0.
I am far enough away (29 blocks)
It is built high up in the sky.
[image: Inside dark room mob spawner with F3 menu open]

Comment: Exactly how far are you going and how long do you wait and how lit up is the area near this?

Comment: I am 26 blocks away from the spawning platforms and i think i dont have to ligt up the caves benauwend of the hight

Comment: Have you tried moving farther away? I thought the mob spawning radius was 32 blocks.

Comment: I think it was 24 but i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

How far away are you exactly from the spawner? And the spawner wich is in the sky works best if its daytime because then the land is lit up, also try to light up as many caves under your mob trap and in the area. Make sure you're not playing on peacefull and if you made the mob trap good, didn't forget any torches in there, didn't forgot to place the water etc..

Comment: I think iam 26 blocks away from the spawning platform. But i didn't lit up the caves because i think its not needed because i am so high up

Comment: How high up is your mobtrap from the surface?